# Can't connect to MySQL client outside of localhost

Tags: mysql

For some reason I am unable to connect to my mysql database outside of the server. The PHP applications running on the server are able to connect through localhost, but not my mysql client on my home computer. Below is my config. can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: are you using some server like WampServer or have you installed a separate MySQL client?

Comment: well, i believe that it was installed by webmin, but I can't get that running for some reason now either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main things to check:

- Is there a firewall inbetween blocking the connection?  From your client you can try `telnet myServerName 3306` to see if you can connect. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html
- Is the user you are trying to connect with allowed to connect from your host?  For more on this refer to the MySQL docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html, specifically `Syntax for account names is 'user_name'@'host_name'.`  If you want to be able to connect with a given account from *any* computer, the account name would follow a syntax like `'user_name'@'%'`, where `%` is a wildcard matching any host name.

Comment: Try to telnet from the client machine to the server machine on port 3306.  Added a reference to my answer.

Comment: i tried with putty, but it did nothing for a while then just made an ugly noise at me and closed.

Comment: Chances are pretty good then that a firewall is blocking your communication between client and server (assuming MySQL is still responding to connections from localhost).

Comment: On a side note, your config file `assume[s] you have at least 32M ram`, meaning you're using one of the default .cfg files as a template.  Unless your database is *tiny*, you want to change many of the memory allocation parameters (for InnoDB or MyISAM depending on which you are using).

Comment: how do I check the firewall settings?

Comment: That depends on your client operating system, your server operating system, and whether your server is behind a dedicated firewall.  Suggest you post a new question to serverfault.com (companion site) describing those details and the fact that you cannot putty from your client to your server on the MySQL port.  You will get better help with firewalls on serverfault.