# c#: Connecting to php Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a small chat program. I want to get data from mysql databse with c#.
But i keep getting an error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

I tried this:

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                     "DATABASE=databse;" +
                     "UID=root;" +
                     "PASSWORD=passowrd";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
```

And it worked. But when i try to connect to a mysql databse other than the one on local host i get an error, and ideas what i can try

Thanks

Comment: What does the error message say? Is the remote database configured for remote access? Does your application have permission to talk to the internet?

Comment: This is the error i get: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Is the server reachable from your machine? Have you tried connecting via e.g. a command line MySQL client?

Comment: That does not really answer my question. Have you checked that it is reachable from the machine you are running the application on?

Comment: Well, the driver for MySQL does not work for MS SQL

Comment: No, i meant MYSQL, i spelled it wrong as "msql"

Comment: some databases are not configured to allow remote connections, this is the issue with my webhost, everytime i want to create a new mysql database I have to choose between remote manageable or no

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//create a MySQL connection with a query string
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=cs;uid=root;password=abcdaaa");

//open the connection
connection.Open();

//close the connection
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that remote connections are allowed to your server. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) you can find some details about that.

Then you should check that the user you are using in the connection string has access from outside localhost. Quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218601/425166) answer:

> Is the user you are trying to connect with allowed to connect from
>   your host? For more on this refer to the MySQL docs at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html and
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html,
>   specifically Syntax for account names is 'user_name'@'host_name'. If
>   you want to be able to connect with a given account from any computer,
>   the account name would follow a syntax like 'user_name'@'%', where %
>   is a wildcard matching any host name.

If none of the above works, you should finally check if there isn't a firewall rule that is blocking your access to the database. There are more details on that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html), but the first thing to try is to telnet the 3306 port on the database server (that is if your database is using the default port).

**PS**: I just spotted that you are using the root user account to connect to the database. By default, root is only able to login from localhost ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html)):

> On Windows, root accounts are created that permit connections from the local host only. Connections can be made by specifying the host
>   name localhost or the IP address 127.0.0.1. If the user selects the
>   Enable root access from remote machines option during installation,
>   the Windows installer creates another root account that permits
>   connections from any host.
>
> On Unix, each root account permits connections from the local host. Connections can be made by specifying the host name localhost,
>   the IP address 127.0.0.1, or the actual host name or IP address.

So you should probably start your investigation with the user level of access. If root is restricted to localhost, it might be a good idea to leave it like that (for security reasons), and create a new user with which to access your database remotely from your application (more details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)).